# Paint on Image after Image loaded from the network

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm loading the images from api call and then showing the image and some data in listview in flutter and drawing bounding box on image, but since my image is getting loaded from url my UI gets disturbed,How I ensure that the Canvas will paint after the image is loaded from the network url in flutter layout.Is there any callbacks which I can use.

```dart
class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ListPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  Future<List<ProcessedInference>> processInference;

  @override
  void initState() {
    processInference = localInference();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final toAppBar = AppBar(
      elevation: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      title: Text(widget.title),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.list),
          onPressed: () {},
        )
      ],
    );

    Card makeCard(ProcessedInference pro) => Card(
          elevation: 2.0,
          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomPaint(
                  size: Size(640.0, 480.0),
                  foregroundPainter: RectPainter(pro.boundingBox),
                  child: Image.network(pro.frameUrl),
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Spotted:  ${pro.peopleCount}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Spotted on : ${pro.timeStamp}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );

    final makeBody = Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<ProcessedInference>>(
        future: processInference,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("Has data");
            if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.length <= 0) {
              return Center(
                  child: Text("No results", textAlign: TextAlign.center));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return makeCard(snapshot.data[index]);
                  });
            }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print("has error ");
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: toAppBar,
      body: makeBody,
    );
  }
}

class RectPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<List<double>> boundingBox;

  RectPainter(this.boundingBox);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.deepOrange;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;

    final boxPaint = Paint();
    boxPaint.color = Colors.amberAccent;
    boxPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    boxPaint.strokeWidth = 2.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < boundingBox.length; i++) {
      var confidence = boundingBox[i][0];
      var left = boundingBox[i][1] * size.width;
      var top = boundingBox[i][2] * size.height;
      var right = boundingBox[i][3] * size.width;
      var bottom = boundingBox[i][4] * size.height;

      var rect = Rect.fromLTRB(left, top - 15, right, bottom);
      canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

      TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red[600], fontSize: 10.0),
          text: confidence.toStringAsFixed(2));
      TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
          text: span,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
      tp.layout();
      canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromLTRB(
              rect.left, rect.top, rect.left + tp.width, rect.top + tp.height),
          boxPaint);
      tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(rect.left, rect.top));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "my UI gets disturbed"?

Comment: Actually canvas paints first and then image gets loaded, so the listview UI flickers when image gets loaded. I want to draw canvas after image get loaded. In android we can do this with Glide to load as bitmap and then draw canvas on that bitmap.